# My spark app does not consistently return data. Why?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, datastax, datastax-enterprise

This is my spark application using spark streaming. The problem is that I do not get data. Around every 5 minutes after running the app it still runs but I don't get any data. I also attached a picture from my spark UI which does not show failed but only empty squares.

I  seperate the different by different times into different spark apps (1 hour, 3 hours, 6 hours etc.) it works just fine. But once I try to put it into 1 spark app it stops every couple of minutes and also doesn't give me any error message.

```
    #coding = utf-8
    import sys
    import json
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, rddsampler
    from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
    from pyspark.streaming.kafka import OffsetRange, KafkaUtils, TopicAndPartition
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
    from dateutil.parser import parse 

    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
    from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel
    import pytz
    tz = pytz.timezone('')


    appname = str(sys.argv[1])
    source = str(sys.argv[2])





    cluster = Cluster(['localhost']); 
    session = cluster.connect('keyspace')
    channel_lookup_stmt = session.prepare("SELECT * FROM channels WHERE id = ?")
    channel_lookup_stmt.consistency_level = ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM


    session_statis = cluster.connect('keyspace')

    def read_json(x):
        try:
            y = json.loads(x)
        except:
            y = 0
        return y

    def TransformInData(x):
        try:
            body = json.loads(x['body'])
            return (body['articles'])
        except:
            return 0


    def axesTransformData(x):
        try:
            body = json.loads(x['body'])
            return (body)
        except:
            return 0
    def axesFlatMap(rdd):
        axess = rdd.map(lambda x:read_json(x[1])).filter(lambda x: x!=0).map(lambda x:axesTransformData(x)).filter(lambda x: x!=0).flatMap(lambda x:(a for a in x))    
        for axes in axess.collect():
            print 'axes value is =========:',axes


    def windowOperation(rdd):
        articles = rdd.map(lambda x:read_json(x[1])).filter(lambda x: x!=0).map(lambda x:TransformInData(x)).filter(lambda x: x!=0).flatMap(lambda x:(a for a in x))
        return articles.filter(lambda x:parse(x['created_at'])>datetime.now(tz)-timedelta(minutes=10)).map(lambda x:(x['id'],x))
        '''
        for article in article_window:
            if parse(article[1]['created_at'])>datetime.now(tz)-timedelta(minutes=10):
                print 'article============:',article[0],parse(article[1]['created_at']),datetime.now(tz)-timedelta(minutes=10)
        '''


    def joinstream(rdd):
    #     print 'joinstream value is ================:',
        session_statis.execute('DELETE FROM statistics WHERE source = %s', [source])
        timeone=datetime.now(tz)-timedelta(hours=1)
        timethree = datetime.now(tz)-timedelta(hours=3)
        timesix = datetime.now(tz)-timedelta(hours=6)
        timetwelve = datetime.now(tz)-timedelta(hours=12)
        timetwentyfour = datetime.now(tz)-timedelta(hours=24)
    #     timethreeday = datetime.now(tz)-timedelta(hours=72)
    #     timeweek = datetime.now(tz)-timedelta(hours=168)
        print 'timeone:%s  timethree:%s timesix:%s timetwelve:%s timetwentyfour:%s' % (timeone,timethree,timesix,timetwelve,timetwentyfour)
        for dr in rdd.distinct().collect():
    #         print 'dr values =================',dr
            for d in dr[1][0].__iter__():
                axes_list = []
                channel = session.execute(channel_lookup_stmt,[d['channel']])
                category=''
                name = ''
                if channel:
                    category = channel[0].category
                    name = channel[0].name
                for daxes in dr[1][1].__iter__():
                    axes_list.append(daxes)
                if len(axes_list)>0:
                    attitudes = max(axes_list,key=lambda x:x['attitudes'])['attitudes']
                    comments = max(axes_list,key=lambda x:x['comments'])['comments']
                    reposts = max(axes_list,key=lambda x:x['reposts'])['reposts']
                    if comments>0 and parse(d['created_at'])>=timeone:
                        session_statis.execute('INSERT INTO statistics(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (source, '1', d['id'], d['title'], d['thumbnail'], d['url'], parse(d['created_at']), category, d['genre'], name, 0, attitudes, comments, reposts, comments))
                    if comments>0 and parse(d['created_at'])>=timethree:
                        session_statis.execute('INSERT INTO statistics(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (source, '3', d['id'], d['title'], d['thumbnail'], d['url'], parse(d['created_at']), category, d['genre'], name, 0, attitudes, comments, reposts, comments))
                    if comments>0 and parse(d['created_at'])>=timesix:
                        session_statis.execute('INSERT INTO statistics(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (source, '6', d['id'], d['title'], d['thumbnail'], d['url'], parse(d['created_at']), category, d['genre'], name, 0, attitudes, comments, reposts, comments))
                    if comments>0 and parse(d['created_at'])>=timetwelve:
                        session_statis.execute('INSERT INTO statistics(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (source, '12', d['id'], d['title'], d['thumbnail'], d['url'], parse(d['created_at']), category, d['genre'], name, 0, attitudes, comments, reposts, comments))
                    if comments>0 and parse(d['created_at'])>=timetwentyfour:
                        session_statis.execute('INSERT INTO statistics(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (source, '24', d['id'], d['title'], d['thumbnail'], d['url'], parse(d['created_at']), category, d['genre'], name, 0, attitudes, comments, reposts, comments))
                else:
                    if d['axes']['comments']>0 and parse(d['created_at'])>=timeone:
                        session_statis.execute('INSERT INTO statistics(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (source, '1', d['id'], d['title'], d['thumbnail'], d['url'], parse(d['created_at']), category, d['genre'], name, 0, d['axes']['likes'], d['axes']['comments'], d['axes']['shares'], d['axes']['comments']))
                    if d['axes']['comments']>0 and parse(d['created_at'])>=timethree:
                        session_statis.execute('INSERT INTO statistics(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (source, '3', d['id'], d['title'], d['thumbnail'], d['url'], parse(d['created_at']), category, d['genre'], name, 0, d['axes']['likes'], d['axes']['comments'], d['axes']['shares'], d['axes']['comments']))
                    if d['axes']['comments']>0 and parse(d['created_at'])>=timesix:
                        session_statis.execute('INSERT INTO statistics(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (source, '6', d['id'], d['title'], d['thumbnail'], d['url'], parse(d['created_at']), category, d['genre'], name, 0, d['axes']['likes'], d['axes']['comments'], d['axes']['shares'], d['axes']['comments']))
                    if d['axes']['comments']>0 and parse(d['created_at'])>=timetwelve:
                        session_statis.execute('INSERT INTO statistics(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (source, '12', d['id'], d['title'], d['thumbnail'], d['url'], parse(d['created_at']), category, d['genre'], name, 0, d['axes']['likes'], d['axes']['comments'], d['axes']['shares'], d['axes']['comments']))
                if d['axes']['comments']>0 and parse(d['created_at'])>=timetwentyfour:
                    session_statis.execute('INSERT INTO statistics(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (source, '24', d['id'], d['title'], d['thumbnail'], d['url'], parse(d['created_at']), category, d['genre'], name, 0, d['axes']['likes'], d['axes']['comments'], d['axes']['shares'], d['axes']['comments']))

conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appname)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc,300)
topic = 'topic1'
kafkaParams = {"metadata.broker.list": "localhost:9092"}


article_stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], kafkaParams)
article_join_stream=article_stream.map(lambda x:read_json(x[1])).filter(lambda x: x!=0).map(lambda x:TransformInData(x)).filter(lambda x: x!=0).flatMap(lambda x:(a for a in x)).map(lambda x:(x['id'].encode("utf-8") ,x))
#axes topic  integration the article and the axes
axes_topic = 'topic2'
axes_stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [axes_topic], kafkaParams)
axes_join_stream = axes_stream.map(lambda x:read_json(x[1])).filter(lambda x: x!=0).map(lambda x:axesTransformData(x)).filter(lambda x: x!=0).flatMap(lambda x:(a for a in x)).map(lambda x:(str(x['id']),x))


#join
statistics = article_join_stream.window(24*60*60,5*60).cogroup(axes_join_stream.window(24*60*60,5*60))
statistics.transform(joinstream).pprint()


ssc.start()    # Start the computation ssc.awaitTermination()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The red squares should have successful data like the others but neither show failed nor give me data

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you reduce the code a bit and provide us with example data?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the streaming UI